# How can I define addition swagger param but not appear in controller/service with Nestjs

Tags: nestjs

I have common `QueryOptionDto` like

```js
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger'
import { TransformArray } from '../decorators'

export class QueryOptionDto {
  @ApiProperty({ example: 1 })
  page?: number
  @ApiProperty({ example: 10 })
  limit?: number
  @ApiProperty({ example: ['name:asc'] })
  @TransformArray
  sort?: string[]
}
```

and I use it in another Dto by extends it

```js
export class GetUserDto extends QueryOptionDto {
  @ApiProperty({ example: 'John'})
  search? : string
}
```

then I use `GetUserDto`  in controller

```js
class UserController {
  @Get()
  get(@Query query : GetUserDto ) {

  }
}
```

I dont want params `page limit sort` appear in controller but still in swagger. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

found it,

I add

```js
@ApiQuery({ type: QueryOptionDto })
@Get()
  get(@Query query : GetUserDto ) {

  }
```